# How to derive end date from start date of other SQL line

Tags: sql-server

So I have this "beautiful" query (I simplified it a bit)

```
select B.IQID, B.NAME, A.IQID, A.START_DATE, NULL as A.END_DATE, CODE, VALUE
from TABLE A
join OTHERTABLE B on A.PORTFOLIO = B.IQID
cross apply (
    values
    ('TRANSOP', A.METANUM1),
    ('CROIS', A.METANUM2),
    ('QUALMAT', A.METANUM3)
) as c (CODE, VALUE)
order by 1,6,4 desc
```

Which gives me a result like that (sorry I can't seem to create a table) :

```
B.IQID   |  B.NAME |    A.IQID |    START_DATE | END_DATE | CODE | VALUE    
1       eResearch       A       2017-08-31      NULL        CROIS       0,0001    
1       eResearch       B       2017-06-30      NULL        CROIS       32,2    
1       eResearch       C       2017-03-31      NULL        CROIS       0    
1       eResearch       D       2015-12-31      NULL        CROIS       70    
1       eResearch       E       2017-03-31      NULL        QUALMAT     100    
1       eResearch       F       2015-12-31      NULL        QUALMAT     20    
1       eResearch       G       2017-03-31      NULL        TRANSOP     0    
1       eResearch       H       2015-12-31      NULL        TRANSOP     10    
2       Technology      I       2015-12-31      NULL        CROIS       70    
2       Technology      J       2017-08-31      NULL        QUALMAT     0    
2       Technology      K       2015-12-31      NULL        TRANSOP     10
```

As you can see here I've added a column named END_DATE but it's empty.
For reporting needs that are to be done on this table, I need to populate the end_date.

This end_date is suppose to be the start_date of the "next" line minus 1 day.
But the "next" line is actually the more recent line for the same B.IQID and the same CODE, leaving NULL if there are no END_DATE applicable.

To clarify I would want to get to this result :

```
B.IQID   |  B.NAME |    A.IQID |    START_DATE | END_DATE | CODE | VALUE    
1       eResearch       A       2017-08-31      NULL        CROIS       0,0001    
1       eResearch       B       2017-06-30      2017-08-30  CROIS       32,2    
1       eResearch       C       2017-03-31      2017-06-29  CROIS       0    
1       eResearch       D       2015-12-31      2017-03-30  CROIS       70    
1       eResearch       E       2017-03-31      NULL        QUALMAT     100    
1       eResearch       F       2015-12-31      2017-03-30  QUALMAT     20    
1       eResearch       G       2017-03-31      NULL        TRANSOP     0    
1       eResearch       H       2015-12-31      2017-03-30  TRANSOP     10    
2       Technology      I       2015-12-31      NULL        CROIS       70    
2       Technology      J       2017-08-31      NULL        QUALMAT     0    
2       Technology      K       2015-12-31      NULL        TRANSOP     10
```

Is it something that seems possible in MSSQL?
Thank you for your help !

Comment: Just adding info here. Although I used IQID as 1, 2, ... or A, B, C..., for the sake of the example, in truth these are alphanumeric chunk of 35 random caracters like 9368C1BFEB4D424C9ADBF7CD007274D0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out `LAG` function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql

You could also join the table on itself, a.name = b.name AND a.iqid = b.iqid + 1, then take b.start_date - 1 day (not sure on the MSSQL syntax for dateadd).

Comment: I'll look at that LAG function right away, thanks !
However my example is missleading I have to admit because my IQIDs are note increasing numbers (more like an alphanumeric chunk of 35 random caracters), so I can't go with IQID + 1

Comment: You could add an identity column in the original query.  Use RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY b.name ORDER BY START_DATE).  But yeah, LAG is probably the better answer.

Comment: So very simple, I just put my initial query in a CTE (minus the order by) and added the following

`select LAG(START_DATE- 1, 1, null)  OVER (PARTITION  by B.IQID, CODE ORDER BY START_DATE desc) AS END_DATE, *
from CTE 
order by 2, 7,5 desc`

Thank you again for the help !